# Windows installation does not recognize the SSD drive

Tags: windows, windows-10, ssd

I have an Asus X515. I had Windows 10 installed and created a partition to install KDE Neon (Ubuntu). The installation was successful, but for some reason, the next day Ubuntu wouldn't boot and got stuck with the Asus logo. Windows booted fine, but I did something that caused a blue screen. I want to reinstall Windows, but I can't, as it doesn't recognize the SSD Kingston NVMe. The ssd appears in the BIOS, and I tried formatting it with a bootable GParted, but Windows still doesn't recognize it. If I boot from a Linux USB, I can see the ssd in the file explorer and even write and upload files to it. Any ideas on how I can solve this? Thanks

Comment: Does it show up in Device Manager (devmgmt.msc) _at all_? (Switch to "View > By connection" and expand down to ACPI and then to PCI Express.) It's one kind of problem if it just doesn't have a drive letter, another if it's not recognized as a disk, yet another if it's missing from the PCI bus entirely.

Comment: Could you please explain a bit more what I should try? I formatted the entire drive. If I boot Windows from a USB drive to install it, it does not recognize any drive. On another USB drive, I have KDE Ubuntu, where I can see the drive.

Comment: The point is that there are multiple levels of an OS "recognizing" a disk of any kind. If it's an NVMe disk, it will show up as a PCI Express device first (alongside the GPU and other PCI-based things); then the OS recognizes it as specifically an NVMe storage device (loading the drivers for it); then it recognizes the partitions that were created; and only _then_ it gets to recognizing the filesystems in those partitions (the whole "formatting" thing). You already said that it doesn't show up as a drive, but you need to trace back from that.

Comment: So you should 1) check whether the disk shows up at all in `diskmgmt.msc` (roughly the Windows equivalent of GParted), and if it does not, then 2) check whether it shows up in Device Manager (`devmgmt.msc`) – somewhat unlikely for it to be completely missing from there, but it might be reporting some kind of problem instead.

Comment: I entered with GParted and created an NTFS partition for half of the disk, leaving the other half unallocated. When I booted with a Windows installation USB and ran "list disk" in the terminal, it didn't recognize the disk, only showing the USB drive.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

It's necessary to manually install the Intel Rapid Storage Technology (IRST) driver.

https://www.asus.com/us/support/FAQ/1044458/

Comment: By doing that you eliminate the possibility of booting to Linux . Intel RST should not be required.

Comment: Can you explain why, or how can I fix it?